# Prevent from another process to access the same ftp stream

Tags: c#, ftp, stream

I'm trying to figure out how can I prevent access to the same ftp stream while I'm still writing to the ftp from another process/computer.

this is the code I try:

```
    internal static bool WriteFileToServer(string urlToWriteOn, string strAllContent)
    {
        Uri ServerUri = new Uri(urlToWriteOn);
        if (ServerUri.Scheme != Uri.UriSchemeFtp)
            return false;

        // Get the object used to communicate with the server.
        FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ServerUri);
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
        byte[] ContentsToWrite = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strAllContent);
        request.ContentLength = ContentsToWrite.Length;

        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(UserID, Password);
        request.UsePassive = false;
        request.KeepAlive = false;
        Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        requestStream.Write(ContentsToWrite, 0, ContentsToWrite.Length);

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);

        requestStream.Close();
        FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        response.Close();
        return true;
    }
```

I made 2 threads that access the function at the same time and both of them stop in the sleep line after they wrote to the ftp (before the close part).
For the test, the first thread wrote 10,000 lines and the second thread wrote 500 lines.

In fact, the first thread is making new file on the ftp and write all the lines and then comes the other thread and rewrite on the first 500 lines (the other 9,500 lines from the first thread keep existing)
I would expect from the second thread to throw an exception, but its not.
I was solving the problem if the code of writing to the ftp was from the same application, but it's going to be written from 2 different computers and I don't want the other computer write to the ftp file simultaneously.

Comment: Do you know something about `Thread synchronization - lock or SyncLock  keywords`?

Comment: Your title _"Prevent from another thread to access the same ftp stream"_ is perhaps misleading because they are arguably **not** the _"same FTP stream"_, same computer or otherwise.  Locally, each thread creates its own stream.  For the multi-computer scenario I would have thought that be handled on the FTP-server side?

Comment: AVD - as I wrote in the question - the lock solution will not help me because the application will run from 2 computers, and I can't sync the access that way.

Comment: Micky Duncan - I understand what you saying  - what is your recommendation for the title?  "Prevent from another thread to access the same ftp file c#" is better?

Comment: TVC - please check my edit, feel free to revert if you think it is not what you are looking for.

Comment: @TVC Thanks.  I think your title should perhaps be something like _how to prevent concurrent writes to a FTP file_

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you are hoping to accomplish is possible from the client side.  My guess is that the better approach would be to write to a 'random' file name or a with a ".inprogress" extension or some such, and then rename the file appropriately once the upload is complete.